# Check whether User and Password match with database

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm not sure how to check for matches on my database when users login and return true if both pass and user match with an entry.

The variables corresponding to the username and password are: `$user` and `$hash`.  And the table where I must look for matches is table `Users` and columns: `User` and `Password`.

How would the query be? Thanks

Comment: Google around for PHP log in forms you will find a *lot* of information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query you need:

```
 SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User = '$user' AND Password = '$hash' LIMIT 1;
```

If that returns a result (you can check with [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)), then the login is valid. If it doesn't, it's invalid. Remember to escape `$user` with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or another escaping function before you use it in the database query.

Answer (score 3):

The query would look similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User='$user' AND Password='$hash' LIMIT 1;
```

Then check if the number of rows == 1. If so, it seems there is a valid login. Remember what you are trying to do: you are trying to match two things in the database. The SQL "AND" makes sure that both conditions are true.

I would check the API on http://mysql.com/ for more information.

Comment: You also need to consider protecting your input, SQL injection is all too easy especially on Login scripts.

Comment: Absolutely. I would recommend writing a `sanitize` method (you can do this with regex, etc.) before sending your input directly into the query.

Comment: Like the explanation.  Was going to add it to mine as well, but you beat me to it by 1 second in posting haha.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Users where User='$user' AND Password='$hash' LIMIT 1
```